# How to POST request for authorization token from filemaker API in c#

Tags: c#, http, post, authorization

I am hitting a POST request to a FileMaker API to get an authorization token but its throwing web exception. How can I fix it?

I have tried it in java. Now I am trying it in c# .NET framework 4.6.1

```
private static void GetToken(string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://exchange.furniflair.com/fmi/data/v1/databases/FurniflairDB/sessions");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("dataapi:Data4me");
        string temp =  Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic ZGF0YWFwaTpEYXRhNG1l");
        string token;
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
             streamWriter.Flush();
        }
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            token = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex){}
}
```

I expect the output to be the authorization token in response, but I am getting only exceptions like httpWebException.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps you set the headers correctly, here is an example that works using PHP.

```
$Post_Json = '{}';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT,443);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Post_Json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
```

This comes from: https://schwarzsoftware.com.au/blogentry.php?id=19
Also ensure that the Data API is turned on in the FileMaker Admin server console, and enabled for the FileMaker file you are trying to access, and access priviliges enabled for that user in the FileMaker file.